# Como faço para mexer uma div verticalmente usando JS puro?

Tags: javascript

Eu consegui mexer horizontalmente usando botões(),e o metodo onlcik , porém quando eu tento fazer o mesmo porém verticalmente usando .style.bottom ou .style.top e tentei mudar o incremento porém  a posição do meu objeto não muda.

html :

```
<div id="caixa"> 
        <div id="caixinha">


        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        &emsp;&emsp;<button onclick = "MovUp()">↑</button>
        <br>
        <button onclick="movimentoDireita()"> ← </button>
        <button onclick="movBaixo">↓</button>
        <button onclick="movimentoEsquerdo()"> →</button>
    </div>
```

css :

```
#caixa{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: green;
            position: relative;   
        }
        #caixinha{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background: red;
            position: absolute;
        }
```

js :

```
        var posH = 0
        var posL = 0
        var caixinhafilha = document.getElementById("caixinha")
        function MovUp(){
            if(posH<=0){

                caixinhafilha.style.top = posH + "px"

            }else{

                posH-- 
                caixinhafilha.style.top = posH + "px"
            }
        }
        function movBaixo(){
            if(posH>=150){

                caixinhafilha.style.bottom = posH + "px"

            }else{

                posH++
                caixinhafilha.style.bottom= posH + "px"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problemas no código:

- Faltam os parênteses ao chamar a função em `onclick="movBaixo"`.
- Na função `movBaixo()`, o `else` deveria ser `style.top`.
- Nas primeiras condições dos `if`'s, você pode colocar o valor em `0`.

```js
var posH = 0
var posL = 0
var caixinhafilha = document.getElementById("caixinha")
function MovUp(){
   if(posH<=0){

       caixinhafilha.style.top = "0"

   }else{

       posH-- 
       caixinhafilha.style.top = posH + "px"
   }
}
function movBaixo(){
   if(posH>=150){

       caixinhafilha.style.bottom = "0"

   }else{

       posH++
       caixinhafilha.style.top= posH + "px"
   }
}
```

```css
#caixa{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background: green;
   position: relative;   
}
#caixinha{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="caixa"> 
  <div id="caixinha">


  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  &emsp;&emsp;<button onclick = "MovUp()">↑</button>
  <br>
  <button onclick="movimentoDireita()"> ← </button>
  <button onclick="movBaixo()">↓</button>
  <button onclick="movimentoEsquerdo()"> →</button>
</div>
```

Comment: agora esta funcionando corretamente,obrigado pela ajuda Sam

Comment: Legal! Se resolveu, pode marcar ✔️ na resposta.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Coé!

Comment: esqueci o B A BA, vou voltar ao primario

Comment: pera q tem outra

Comment: que é isso `$registro["idrole"] = $cur->fields["idrole"];` sendo `$cur = $conn->execute($SQL);`

Comment: xiii, isso é php kkkkk

Comment: tah sofrendo de amnésia? rs

Comment: como eu faço para marcar a resposta?